# Prove: $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ $\implies$ $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^{-1}$ with an eigenvalue of $\frac{1}{\lambda}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that $$det(AA^{-1})=det(I)=1$$ And because $$det(AA^{-1})=det(A)det(A^-1)$$ So: $$det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{det(A)}$$ But not sure how to go from here and if that's even useful, because $A-\lambda I$ is singular and there is no way to express the sum of 2 matrices ([Expressing the determinant of a sum of two matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673934/expressing-the-determinant-of-a-sum-of-two-matrices)).

(Clues would be more appreciated than solutions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Start from $Av = \lambda v$ and multiply by $A^{-1}$ from the left.

Answer (score 2):

$Av=\lambda v$ and if $A^{-1}$ exists.then we can operate $A^{-1}$ in both sides to get $$v=A^{-1}\lambda v$$
$$\frac{v}{\lambda}=A^{-1}v$$

Answer (score 1):

$$Av=\lambda v$$
Multiply $A^{-1}$ from the left on both sides:
$$A^{-1}Av=Iv=v=A^{-1}\lambda v$$
Multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{\lambda}$:
$$\frac{1}{\lambda}v=\frac{1}{\lambda}(A^{-1}\lambda v)=\frac{1}{\lambda}(\lambda A^{-1}v) =   A^{-1}v$$
Proving that $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $v$ for $A^{-1}$