# Real matrices whose squares sum up to $O_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that if $A, B \in M_2(\mathbb{R}) $, $AB=BA$, $\det(A+iB) =0$ and $4 \det A > (Tr A) ^2$, then $A^2+B^2=O_2$.
From $\det (A+iB) =0$ I got that $\det A=\det B$ and $Tr A\cdot Tr B=Tr(AB) $, but I don't know how to use this.

Comment: determinant of sum of 2x2 matrices: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673934/expressing-the-determinant-of-a-sum-of-two-matrices $(A + B)^2 = A^2 + AB + BA + B^2$

Comment: How is this relevant to the problem?

Comment: Hint: if $C$ is a real 2-by-2 matrix with an eigenvalue $i$, then $C^2=-I$.

Comment: How to use this?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is a real square matrix, its determinant and its trace are real numbers.  As $$4\,\det(A)>\big(\text{trace}(A)\big)^2\geq 0\,,$$ we have $\det(A)\neq 0$, so $A$ is invertible.  Take $C:=A^{-1}\,B$.  Then, $C$ is a real matrix such that $$\det(I+\text{i}\,C)=0\,,$$ where $I$ is the $2$-by-$2$ identity matrix.  Use this to prove that $\text{i}$ is an eigenvalue of $C$, and then apply user1551's hint.  With $C^2=-I$ and $AB=BA$, show that $A^2+B^2=0$.

Comment: Why is $\det(I+iC) =0$?

Comment: Because $\det(A+\text{i}\,B)=\det(A)\,\det\left(I+\text{i}\,A^{-1}\,B\right)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to solve it!