# Sums of vector triangles and a resultant identity of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, determinant

In the $\mathbb R^2$ plane, let $a, b, c$ be vectors, let $o$ be the origin, and let $d = b + c$.  Determine the area of $\triangle oad$ in terms of $\triangle oab$ and $\triangle oac$, and infer an identity regarding the [determinant of a sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298454/the-determinant-of-a-sum-of-matrices?noredirect=1&lq=1).  *(Source: Inspired by [this problem](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/chapter04/section01.html).)*

My solution is below.  I request verification, critique, or alternate approaches.

WLOG, assume $a = i$ (that is, $[1 \quad 0]^\top$).  Since [the area of triangles on the same base depends only on height](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangles_with_Equal_Base_and_Same_Height_have_Equal_Area), the area of $\triangle oab$ is a directly proportional function of $b_2$ (but independent of $b_1$).  Similarly, the area of $\triangle oac$ is a directly proportional function of $c_2$.

Consider the case when $b$ and $c$ are in the same half-plane induced by $a$ (that is, either both above or both below).  Then the height of $\triangle oad$ equals $b_2 + c_2$, and so the area of $\triangle oad$ equals the sum of the areas of $\triangle oab$ and $\triangle oac$.

In the other case, with $b$ and $c$ in different half-planes, the height of $\triangle oad$ equals $b_2 - c_2$, and the area of $\triangle oad$ is the difference in areas of $\triangle oab$ and $\triangle oac$.

We can simplify the above by using signed areas.  Then, in either case, the signed area of $\triangle oad$ equals the sum of the signed areas of $\triangle oab$ and $\triangle oac$.

Since determinants in $\mathbb R^2$ are equal to signed area, this shows that $$\det([A \quad (B+C)]) = \det([A \quad B]) + \det([A \quad C])$$ that is, **determinants are linear in each column.**

I'm not able to determine if this identity generalizes.

Comment: The determinant of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{K}^n$ is an $n$-linear alternating form. This is one possible definition of the determinant.

Comment: I'm repeating here in the notes: you need to add the case where $b + c$ is linearly dependent to $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working in a vector space already it follows that the area of a triangle composed of vectors $\triangle 0 \vec a \vec d = \frac{1}{2} | \vec a \times \vec d |$.

Then cross product identities give

$$ \frac{1}{2} | \vec a \times \vec d | =  \frac{1}{2} | \vec a \times (\vec b + \vec c) | $$

$$ = \frac{1}{2} | \vec a \times \vec b + \vec a \times \vec c | $$

$$ \le \frac{1}{2} | \vec a \times \vec b | + \frac{1}{2} | \vec a \times \vec c|$$

Finally the determinant of a matrix is related to the cross product in a natural way.

Comment: Thanks.  The inequality seems weak.  My proof above shows it's actually equal, no?

Comment: In this case equality follows immediately since the areas are positive definite.

Comment: I'd recommend writing this out using more notation and less paragraphs which are hard to read.

Comment: Okay I stepped through and think there's a case you missed which is, what if the vectors $b + c$ add to be on the axis you have oriented $a$ with?  This is the case where $b + c = ka$ for some $k$ in the field and so the two vectors are linearly dependent?